# formulario Jsp Verificación de autos

Tags: jsp

Necesito que este formulario sea un registro para autos he intentado pero no me sale, ya que es con JSP.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <center>
   <h1>
    Bienvenido administrador
    </h1>
 <div class="cerrar"><a href="">Cerrar sesión</a> </div>
  <div class="container">
   <table class="tabla">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Id_carro
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="id" placeholder="id carro">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Matricula
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="matricula" placeholder="matricula">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>
           Propietario
       </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="propietario" placeholder="propietario">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Tipo de verificación
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="verificacion" placeholder="verificación">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Reporte
        </td>
        <td>
            <textarea class="mensaje" name="mensaje" cols="50" rows="5" required="required" placeholder="realiza tu reporte"></textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Fecha de verificación
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="date" class="date" placeholder="verificación">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Fecha proxima de verificación
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="date" class="date" placeholder="verificación">
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
       <center>
        <td class="botones" colspan="2">
            <input class="agregar" type="button" value="Agregar">
            <input class="modif" type="button" value="Modificar">
            <input class="soli" type="button" value="solicitar reporte">
            <input class="eliminar" type="button" value="Eliminar">
        </td>
        </center>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Por favor tomate el tiempo de mejorar tus titulos, no es necesario colocar ayuda en ellas ya que nos distrae.

Comment: Un par de cosas a que tengas en cuenta, si es un formulario y no tiene un "tag" form con sus respectivos atributos, me da a pensar que enviás los datos por javascript, si no es ninguno de los casos anteriores calcúlo que querés saber cómo se hacen, si podés sé explicito con los archivos que tenés, manejás servlets? es un servicio Rest? en conclusión un pregunta un poco más elaborada.